# How to find resource groups of particular resource in az cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have resource name , but I have to find resource group to which resource belongs. It needs to be done using az cli

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command below to list resources by resource name :

```
az resource list -n '<resource name>'
```

So that you can find `resourceGroup` property in result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers provided, if you wanted to filter the results of `az resource list` to show just the resource group name, you could query the json output for the `resourceGroup` key and then output as tab-separated values.

```
az resource list -n resource-name --query "[].resourceGroup" -o tsv
```

Which will just output like this:

```
ked@mac:~/repos|master ⇒  az resource list -n my-resource --query "[].resourceGroup" -o tsv 
my-rg
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli) the azure documentation that shows how to format output.